# Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I have created two tomcat instances and changed the AJP port as below.

```
<Connector port="1983" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8553" address="0.0.0.0" />
```

Then I have edited the worker.properties and add this port as below.

```
worker.app2Worker.type=ajp13
worker.app2Worker.host=serapp.abcapp.com
worker.app2Worker.port=1983
```

I have modified the ssl.conf and this worker.
But I got below error.

```
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (817): connect to 14.178.78.77:1983 failed (errno=13)
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1068): (app2Worker) Failed opening socket to (14.178.78.77:1983) (errno=13)
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1728): (app2Worker) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2778): (app2Worker) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (817): connect to 14.178.78.77:1983 failed (errno=13)
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1068): (app2Worker) Failed opening socket to (14.178.78.77:1983) (errno=13)
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1728): (app2Worker) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2778): (app2Worker) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2799): (app2Worker) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=1, client_errors=0).
[Wed Jan 30 08:37:51 2019] [15458:140454934608000] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2995): Service error=-3 for worker=app2Worker
```

Webserver: Apache 7 
App server: Tomcat 8

Can you please advise what is the wrong here?

Comment: Is tomcat started and listening on the right port?

Comment: Yes. I can telnet to that port from Apache web server

Answer (score 1):

For me it was selinux blocking the connection, needed to adjust the policy: https://serverfault.com/questions/563872/selinux-allow-httpd-to-connect-to-a-specific-port

Answer (score 0):

Please find my investigation and answer for the above issue :

`factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"`
`maxActive="100"`
`maxIdle="20"`
`maxWait="10000"`
`validationInterval="60000"`
`minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="600000"`
`removeAbandoned="true"`
`removeAbandonedTimeout="600"`
`logAbandoned="true"`
`timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"`

***After adding these parameters Tomcat need to restart***

Its solved my problem hope it will help you :)